# Related Blog Post in SilverStripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

How do we get related blog post in SilverStripe that are related by Categories or Tags?

Or is there any solution to change this snippet to call all Tags (depends on tags of that blog post), not on (%news%)?:

```
function LatestNews($num = 5) { 
    return DataObject::get("ArticlePage", "Tags LIKE '%news%' ", "Date DESC", "", $num); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `BlogPost` `Extension` to add a `RelatedCategoryPosts` function and a `RelatedTagPosts` function:

```
class BlogPostExtension extends DataExtension {

    public function RelatedCategoryPosts() {
        $relatedPosts = ArrayList::create();

        foreach ($this->owner->Categories() as $category) {
            $relatedPosts->merge($category->BlogPosts());
        }

        $relatedPosts->removeDuplicates();
        $relatedPosts->remove($relatedPosts->byID($this->owner->ID));

        return $relatedPosts;
    }

    public function RelatedTagPosts() {
        $relatedPosts = ArrayList::create();

        foreach ($this->owner->Tags() as $tag) {
            $relatedPosts->merge($tag->BlogPosts());
        }

        $relatedPosts->removeDuplicates();
        $relatedPosts->remove($relatedPosts->byID($this->owner->ID));

        return $relatedPosts;
    }
}
```

To enable this we add this extension to our config.yml

```
BlogPost:
  extensions:
    - BlogPostExtension
```

Now in our custom `BlogPost` template we can call these functions to retrieve the related posts:

```
<% if $RelatedCategoryPosts %>
    <h2>Related posts</h2>
    <ul>
        <% loop $RelatedCategoryPosts %>
            <li><a href="$Link">$Title</a></li>
        <% end_loop %>
    <ul>
<% end_if %>
```